# Ignore empty match php Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, removing-whitespace

I need to replace all of the text within the tag (which is not a code).
So I'm using:

```
preg_replace('/<.*?>([^<]*)<\/.*?>/', "new_text", $str)
```

And I get a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34sHz.png). But I need to remove all empty and onlywhitespace matches or eliminate them from the search.
How can i do it?

Comment: Use `+`: `preg_replace('/<.*?>([^<]+)<\/.*?>/', "new_text", $str)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yep! Thank you!

Comment: Using a `+` will remove empty matches, but not whitespace only matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this :

```
<.*?>((?=[^<]*\S.*?<)([^<]+))<\/.*?>
```

or, if you want to include newlines in your match :

```
(<.*?>)(?=[^<]*\S.*[<\n])([^<]+)(<\/.*?>)
```

[Here's a demo](http://regexr.com/3dkd6)

It's similar to your awnser in replacing your matching group with `[^<]+` to make sure at least one character is returned

However, to make sure that whitespace only strings won't be matched, there is a look-ahead that is added after the opening tag match :

```
(?=[^<]*\S.*?<)
```

This makes sure that between the two tags there is at least one character that isn't whitespace.

[more info on lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Prompt please, what can I add to highlight text of [this type](http://regexr.com/3dkha)?

Comment: That's it `(?=[^<]*\S\s*?<)` ?

Comment: But I need only text (without tabs and whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m98bz.png):

```
preg_replace('/<.*?>([^<]*)<\/.*?>/', "new_text", $str)
```

[After:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3w7Q.png)

```
Use +: preg_replace('/<.*?>([^<]+)<\/.*?>/', "new_text", $str)
```